# Trying to pull just the MAX Date from inner joined tables

Tags: mysql

```
Select distinct 
      crt.Tariff,  crte.PrintDescription, cre.Element,
      cret.ElementTemplate, cred.EffectiveDate , crtfc.TrafficClass, crec.RateDecimal
From  cabratetariffelement crte
      inner join cabratetariff crt on crte.tariffid = crt.tariffid
      inner join cabratetariffclass crtc on crt.tariffclassid = crtc.tariffclassid
      inner join cabrateelement cre on crte.elementid = cre.elementid
      inner join CABRateElementTemplate cret on cre.ElementTemplateID = cret.ElementTemplateID
      inner join cabrateelementdate cred on crte.elementid = cred.elementid
      inner join cabrateelementcharge crec on cred.elementdateid = crec.elementdateid
      inner join cabratetrafficclass crtfc on crec.trafficclassid = crtfc.trafficclassid
```

Trying to just get the most recent EffectiveDate from the CABRateElementDate table.........

Comment: Sure, and what's the problem? Does it not work? Are you getting any errors? Are you expecting to see something else than you are seeing? Could you provide more details for us to work with so we can help you?:)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
      crt.Tariff,  crte.PrintDescription, cre.Element,
      cret.ElementTemplate, max(cred.EffectiveDate) , crtfc.TrafficClass, crec.RateDecimal
From  cabratetariffelement crte
      inner join cabratetariff crt on crte.tariffid = crt.tariffid
      inner join cabratetariffclass crtc on crt.tariffclassid = crtc.tariffclassid
      inner join cabrateelement cre on crte.elementid = cre.elementid
      inner join CABRateElementTemplate cret on cre.ElementTemplateID = cret.ElementTemplateID
      inner join cabrateelementdate cred on crte.elementid = cred.elementid
      inner join cabrateelementcharge crec on cred.elementdateid = crec.elementdateid
      inner join cabratetrafficclass crtfc on crec.trafficclassid = crtfc.trafficclassid
group by crt.Tariff,  crte.PrintDescription, cre.Element,
      cret.ElementTemplate, crtfc.TrafficClass, crec.RateDecimal
```

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'cabratetariff.Tariff' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I get the above error when all I do is add MAX in front of my cred.EffectiveDate.................